# A general method to parse nested expressions

Tags: python, nested, binary-tree, boolean-expression

I have string expressions of the following forms:

```
"( ( ( D & E ) | B ) & ( A | C ) )"
"( ( A & B ) | ( C ^ D ) )"
"( ( ( A & B ) | ( C ^ D )  ) & E )"
"( E & ( A & ( B   | ( C ^ D ) ) ) )"
```

Elements in the list `['A', 'B', 'C', D', 'E']` represent systems and those in the list `['&', '|', '^']` represent boolean operations.

I need to parse each expression based on the nesting of the parentheses. Each expression should be evaluated from the innermost nested statement.

For example: `"( ( ( D & E ) | B ) & ( A | C ) )"` would be parsed into the following list

```
[('C', 'A'),
 ('C', '( C | A )'),
 ('A', '( C | A )'),
 ('E', 'D'),
 ('E', '( E & D )'),
 ('D', '( E & D )'),
 ('B', '( E & D )'),
 ('( B | ( E & D ) )', '( C | A )')]
```

while `"( ( A & B ) | ( C ^ D ) )"` would be parsed into:

```
[('A', '( A & B )'),
 ('B', '( A & B )'),
 ('C', '( C ^ D )'),
 ('D', '( C ^ D )'),
 ('( A & B )', '( C ^ D )')]
```

etc.

The expected result starts from innermost nested expressions within the expression, e.g., `( A & B )` and compares each system element to this to get the list tuple elements `('A', '( A & B )')` and `('B', '( A & B )')`,  and then traverses outwards within the expression till the outermost expression is reached, e.g., `('( A & B )', '( C ^ D )')`.

To get the order of how these expressions are evaluated in a parse tree (`['D', 'C', '^', 'B', 'A', '&', '|']`for the second example) I created methods based on Miller and Ranum's parse tree algorithm as found here [Parse Tree](https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/Trees/ParseTree.html). The methods I then created are based on this, but extremely specific to each expression type. I would post my code here, but it is very long and convoluted, and as such is useless.

I am wondering if I am overthinking this and if there is a much simpler way of parsing general expressions like those given above?

Comment: just use pyparsing to create a grammar... its not trivial ... but you havent given enough info for more ...

Comment: Well one thing I can say is this isn't easy.

Comment: I don't understand your expected result.

Comment: It is definitely easier to use `pyparsing` or a similar tool than to try to write a parser from scratch.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I updated the details above to hopefully make this more clear. I'll definitely look at `pyparsing`.

Comment: What do you want to do with the result and why aren't you doing all of it with sympy?